# Jquery find element with data starting with some value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a sintax to search inside data of a element starting with a given value, with or without an underscore after it. For example if a give a number like `3`:

```
<span data-filter="3_1"></span>   // I NEED TRUE
<span data-filter="3"></span>   // I NEED TRUE
<span data-filter="33_1"></span>   // I NEED FALSE
<span data-filter="1_3"></span>   // I NEED FALSE
```

`$(span[filter^="3"])` doesn't work for 3° example.

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fdphzogc/1/

Of course i've inserted an example like `3`, but it can be another number with more digits like 465_12, where 465 is what i'm looking for

Comment: You're using the wrong quotes in `$(span[filter^=”3”])`. Use either `'` or `"`, not `”`

Comment: I think this would be a job for the good'ol RegEx. I'm still really bad at RegEx but this might help you get some understanding of what you should be looking for [Regexr](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, you want all `<span>` which have a `data-filter` that either has a `3` or, start with `3_`

For the `data-filter="3"` you can use

```
$('span[data-filter="3"]')
```

For the `data-filter="3_ .... "` you can use:

```
$('span[data-filter^="3_"]')
```

Both together:

```
$('span[data-filter="3"],span[data-filter^="3_"]')
```

In a demo:

```css
span { display: block; }
span[data-filter="3"],
span[data-filter^="3_"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span data-filter="3_1">3_1</span>
<span data-filter="3">3</span>
<span data-filter="33_1">33_1</span>
<span data-filter="1_3">1_3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is after you defined your truth table, you have to translate it into a high-level language.

For example, if I read your post (without the code) I understood you are looking for everything starting with 3.

But if I read your snippet I understood you are looking for exactly "3" or starting "3_". 
If this last sentence is true:

```
$('span[data-filter^="3_"], span[data-filter="3"]')
```

Comment: You didn't try in the right way. I updated your fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/fdphzogc/8/